# JQuery Tic Tac Toe 2 Players

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

would like to seek advices from you guys. I'm a beginner only. :( I'm trying to make a game, a 2 Player Tic Tac Toe though I'm not yet in the functionality part. What can you suggest here in implementing the game?

What I am trying to do is that I want to disable the "div" once the player clicked it and I have no idea yet how to implement that using JQuery. TIA.

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
            var player1 = true;
            var player2 = true;
            var O = "<img id='o1' src='img/O.png' value='o'/>";
            var X = "<img id='x1' src='img/X.png' value='x'/>";

            function resetP1() {
                player1 = true;
            }

            function resetP2() {
                player2 = true;
            }

            $(".box").click(function() {
                //var value = $(this).attr('value');
                //$(this).hide();

                if(player1) {
                    $(this).html(X);
                    player1 = false;
                    resetP2();
                } else {
                    $(this).html(O);
                    player2 = false;
                    resetP1();
                }

            });
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
        <div id="b1" value="b1" class="box">

        </div>
        <div id="b2" value="b2" class="box">

        </div>
        <div id="b3" value="b3" class="box">

        </div>
        <div id="b4" value="b4" class="box">

        </div>
        <div id="b5" value="b5" class="box">

        </div>
        <div id="b6" value="b6" class="box">

        </div>
        <div id="b7" value="b7" class="box">

        </div>
        <div id="b8" value="b8" class="box">

        </div>
        <div id="b9" value="b9" class="box">

        </div>
```

Comment: put in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/ANyYM/ and hit "update" when you are finished.

Comment: you can use .off("click") [http://api.jquery.com/off/](http://api.jquery.com/off/) or .one("click",function) [http://api.jquery.com/one/](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do "$(this).html(X);", this is a reference to document, and html() try to override all his content with X, but X isn't a string!

for example you can make a < table >, and in js:

```
<script>

// Encapsulation to preserve scope
(function(){

var currentPlayer = "X";

function changePlayer(){
    if( currentPlayer  == "X" )
        currentPlayer = "O";
    else
        currentPlayer = "X";
}

jQuery("td").each(function(){
    // This = current TD
    jQuery(this).click(function(){
        jQuery(this).html( currentPlayer );
        jQuery(this).unbind("click");
        changePlayer();
        // and call some function to evaluate the board
    })

});

})();

<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing would be to add an ID attribute to it, something like this:

```
<div id="b9" value="b9" class="box">

</div>
```

Then in jQuery try adding the ID as

```
$('box').click(function () {
   /* among all other code */
   $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + ' disabled');
}
```

Now the DIV would have a disabled id to,

Then when you click on the box, check for the ID of that div, if it has `disabled` id, `return false`.

Comment: I tried doing this but I don't know why something weirds happens. My layout gets broken also.

Answer (score 0):

/* Main Game Handling class */
var instructions = "This is a two player Tic Tac Toe game. The objective of the game is to get three items of same kind in a row/column/diagonal. Click on a cell to mark it with your symbol. Tag your friend along with you to enjoy this game.";
var TicTacToe = {
    turn: "O",  // Keeps a record of who's turn it is
    board: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],  // Keeps a record of the TicTacToe Board
    win: false, // records who won if the game is over

```
/* Clears and starts a new game with a new board */
restartGame: function () {
    // Draw the board
    alert("anil singhania");
    var board_table = '<table class="board" border="0px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" align="center"><tr><td id="ttt0">&nbsp;</td><td id="ttt1">&nbsp;</td><td id="ttt2">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td id="ttt3">&nbsp;</td><td id="ttt4">&nbsp;</td><td id="ttt5">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td id="ttt6">&nbsp;</td><td id="ttt7">&nbsp;</td><td id="ttt8">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>';
    $("#board").html(board_table);
    $("#menu").hide();

    // clear the board
    this.board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

    // Add on-click events to each of the boxes of the board
    $("#board td").click(function (e) {
        TicTacToe.move(e.target.id);
    });

},

/* Handles clicks spaces on the board */
move: function (id) {
    var space = $("#" + id);  // Board space table element
    var num = id.replace("ttt", ""); // # representing the space on the board

    // If no one's gone there, and the game isn't over, go there!
    if (!this.board[num] && !this.win) {
        space.html(this.turn);
        this.board[num] = this.turn;
        this.nextTurn();  // End turn
    }
},

/* Iterate turn and check if anyone one yet */
nextTurn: function () {
    this.turn = (this.turn == "O") ? "X" : "O";
    this.win = this.check4Win();
    if (this.win) {
        this.endGame();
    }
},

/* Display who won and options for new games */
endGame: function () {

    if (this.win == "Cat") {
        $("#menu").html("Game<br /> Over.");
        $("#board").off("click");
    } else {
        $("#menu").html(this.win + " wins!");
        $("#board").off("click");
    }
    $("#menu").append("<div id='play_again'>Play Again</div>");

    // Button for playing again.
    $("#play_again").click(function () { TicTacToe.restartGame(); });
    $("#menu").show();
    this.win = false;

},

// If any of these patters of board spaces have all X's or all O's somebody won!
wins: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [6, 4, 2]],

/* Check for whether someone won the game of it was a Cat's game. */
check4Win: function () {

    // Loop through all possible winning combinations 
    for (k in this.wins) {
        var pattern = this.wins[k];
        var p = this.board[pattern[0]] + this.board[pattern[1]] + this.board[pattern[2]];
        if (p == "XXX") {
            return "X";  // X Won!
        } else if (p == "OOO") {
            return "O";  // O Won!
        }
    }

    // Check if all spaces in the board are filled, then its a Cat's game
    var cnt = 0;
    for (s in this.board) {
        if (this.board[s]) { cnt += 1; }
    }
    if (cnt == 9) {
        return "Cat";  // Cat's game!
    }
}
```

};

$(document).ready(function () {

```
// Start a game!
TicTacToe.restartGame();
$('.instructions').click(function () {
    alert(instructions);
});
```

});

```
enter code here
```